# Getting "Installing..." for too long, during any app installation attempt

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery-life, installation, side-loading, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I cannot install any app on my Galaxy Note 8 N5100 tablet which is rooted and uses Android 4.4.2. It takes too much time with no result.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

And this is the status of my package installer app:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

---

**Edit:**
I think I found what's the problem. This is the battery usage of my device:
You see the usage of `Google play services` is very high about 47%

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
I think it's the cause of these problems:

- When I try to play a film, it stops time to time
- Installation of applications takes a lot of time
- Battery usage is very high
- The devise is warm even if I'm not using it

What should I do to solve the problem?
It's not possible to uninstall `Google play services` and reinstall it

Comment: "*It takes too much time with no result*" -- do you see any error message or anything? Does the installation ends on its own or do you manually do something to end it? May be logging can help here. Use [tag:logcat] to start logging then attempt to install the app. Give us the logs then as a link (use a code paste service). If needed, see [How to Logcat](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238)?

Comment: @Firelord in fact if I don't do anything, the application will be installed after several hours but there are other problems too. The battery usage is far more higher than before and when I'm trying to play a movie, it stops time to time (the device hangs alot)

Answer (score -1):

Best attempts to make your phone fast and long lasting is using some powerful apps which work only of your phone is rooted. Root your phone and download apps like greenify (for battery purpose), roehsoft ram expander (for faster and smoother performance), titanium backup and link to SD (for uninstalling bloatware and transferring apps to SD card which cannot be done through setting without root. 
So u need root access for your phone to use these apps. 
Rooting your phone can be done through PC by kingoroot, volcano box, etc
And through your phone by kingroot, super su and super user.

I guess this will solve all your problems.. All the best....

Comment: My phone is rootted

Comment: Would you care to explain how your answer addresses the question, specially the part "*Installation of applications takes a lot of time*"?

Answer (score -1):

Even if your phone is rooted, you may be not utilizing the root access properly. Simply rooting the phone doesn't make it fast, save the battery and all.

By rooting the phone, you should even make use of the root by installing proper apps which need root access to work. For no ads in the phone, there is an app called adaway, for battery saving there is greenify, and the list goes on. Search in Google for apps which need root access and you will get fascinating apps.

Comment: You can always comment on your own post. I believe your  post is a reply to [this comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127431/getting-installing-for-too-long-during-any-app-installation-attempt/127585#comment158155_127564)

Answer (score -1):

When there is more ram usage or more internal memory usage, the phone will be slow and thus the installation. So u need to free your ram and your phone internal storage to speed things up.

So by using the above mentioned apps, you can speed your phone by making reducing the usage of your phone's ram.